# Pasar Objeto de Servlet a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hola espero me puedan ayudar llevo mucho tiempo queriendo solucionar este problema. 
A continuación muestro mi código.
Tengo una `Página JSP` llamada **Index.jsp**.

```
<form action="ServletPersona" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="txtNombre"><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtApellidoPat"><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtApellidoMat"><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtDni"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Tengo una `Clase java` sencilla llamada **"Persona"**

```
public class Persona {
    private String Nombre;
    private String ApellidoPat;
    private String ApellidoMat;
    private String Dni;

// Tengo creado un constructor vacio y los métodos getter y setter.
}
```

Tengo un `Servlet` llamada **"ServletPersona"**

```
String Nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
String ApellidoPat = request.getParameter("txtApellidoPat");
String ApellidoMat = request.getParameter("txtApellidoMat");
String Dni = request.getParameter("txtDni");

if(Nombre.length() == 0 || ApellidoPat.length() == 0 || ApellidoMat.length() == 0 || Dni.length() == 0){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Mensaje.jsp?mens='Los campos no pueden estar vacios.'").forward(request, response);
}else{
    Persona Pers = new Persona(Nombre, ApellidoPat, ApellidoMat, Dni);
    request.setAttribute("Pers", Pers); 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Mensaje.jsp?mens='Usted acaba de ser registrado.'").forward(request, response);  
}
```

Y tengo mi `Página JSP` donde voy a mostrar el resultado llamada **Mensaje.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">
        <%
            if(request.getParameter("mens")!=null){
                out.println(request.getParameter("mens"));
            }
        %>
    </h1><br>

    ${Pers.Nombre}<br>
    ${Pers.ApellidoPat}<br>
    ${Pers.ApellidoMat}<br>
    ${Pers.Dni}<br>
</body>
```

Bueno no se como llamar los valores de la Clase **"Persona"** a la Página **"Mensaje.jsp"**, la variable de la "URL" `mens` si me muestra pero no los valores de la clase, además me sale este mensaje solo cuando lleno todos los campos del formulario.
`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.web.modelo.clases.Persona' does not have the property 'Nombre'.`
**Alguna sugerencia para resolver este problema**, espero haber sido muy comprensible.
**Nota:** Estoy incluyendo `JSTL` en mi JSP.

Comment: Prueba a poner los nombres de campos en `Persona` en minúsculas, así: `nombre`, `apellidoPat` etc. Y lo mismo cuando los recuperas: `Pers.nombre`.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev muchas gracias si salió pero porque razón a mi no me llamaba con las variables que empezaban con mayúsculas, no se si me podrías explicar eso o ¿es sintaxis de java?. De todos modos gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver como aclaramos el asunto.

Tienes una clase `Persona` definida así:

```
public class Persona {
    private String Nombre;
    private String ApellidoPat;
    private String ApellidoMat;
    private String Dni;

// getter y setter
}
```

Y luego, en la jsp, intentas usar esta clase así:

```
${Pers.Nombre}<br>
${Pers.ApellidoPat}<br>
${Pers.ApellidoMat}<br>
${Pers.Dni}<br>
```

En un principio parece bien pero en realidad hay un conflicto de nombres y/o métodos.

Supongo que en la clase `Persona` los métodos get y set los has definido así:

```
public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
}
```

Parece bien y funciona si lo invocas sobre una instancia de la clase `Persona`. Lo que no funciona es cuando el framework de la jsp lo invoca. Por regla general los nombres de variables en java empiezan por minúscula, igual que los nombres de métodos, y en java se usa *camelCase*. Por la misma que cuando ves un método `getNombre` piensas que la clase sobre la que se invoca este método tiene un campo `nombre`, no piensas en `Nombre`. (En realidad el método se invoca sobre una instancia de la clase, no sobre la clase)

No sabría decir qué, exactamente, hace el entorno por dentro cuando tu le pides `Pers.Nombre`. Si le pides `Pers.nombre`, este intentará ejecutar el método `getNombre` sobre el objeto `Pers`. En este caso a lo mejor intenta hacer algo como `getnombre` que, obviamente, no existe. No lo sé y tampoco voy a buscar código para ver cómo se ejecuta esto, pero a rasgos generales es buena idea (y después de lo visto - muy buena) seguir la nomenclatura de los nombres en java.

En definitiva:

nombres de variables y métodos - empiezan en minúscula

nombres de clases - empiezan en mayúscula

y se utiliza *camelCase*.

Espero que esto te aclare un poco el funcionamiento y el por qué de tu error.

Saludos